# How do I send request payload as JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know, this sounds naive (and probably is), but I can't figure out how to make a jquery ajax request with a jason body. Everything I read about it, says that just setting `contentType` to `application/json` should be enough, but it does not seem to be the case.

Here is what I am doing:

```
   $.ajax({  
     url: "http://localhost:8080/put-stuff",
     context: document.body,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     method: "PUT",
     data:  { "foo": "bar", "baz": { "bat": 1 } }
   })
```

But the payload it ends up sending looks like this: `foo=bar&baz%5Bbat%5D=1`
What other incantation do I need to make it send it as json?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ "foo": "bar", "baz": { "bat": 1 } })`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! It actually occurred to me to try that, but I think I put it in quotes (like ` "${JSON.stringify(...}"`) when I did, so it didn't work.